# Can't access queue from IronWorker with .NET

Tags: iron.io, ironmq

I just started experimenting with Iron.io, using .NET and IronTools. I'm able to Push and Get a message to a queue from a desktop app just fine. Now I want to create a worker to Get a message from a queue, process it, and Push it to another queue. The worker is failing with the following error in the log:

> Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: Error getting response stream (Write: The authentication or decryption has failed.): SendFailure ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: Invalid certificate received from server. Error code: 0xffffffff800b0109
>    at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.Client.TlsServerCertificate.validateCertificates (Mono.Security.X509.X509CertificateCollection certificates) [0x00000] in :0
>    at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.Client.TlsServerCertificate.ProcessAsTls1 () [0x00000] in :0
>    at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.HandshakeMessage.Process () [0x00000] in :0
>    at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.HandshakeMessage:Process () 
>    at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.ClientRecordProtocol.ProcessHandshakeMessage (Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsStream handMsg) [0x00000] in :0
>    at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.InternalReceiveRecordCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in :0

Here's the code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Started worker1");  
IronMQ imqRead = new IronMQ("micu5", "project_id", "token");  
Console.WriteLine("Created imqRead object");  
IronIO.Data.Message msg = imqRead.Get();  
Console.WriteLine("imqRead.Get succeeded");
```

(Actual project ID and token have been removed from the code above)

What am I missing?

Edit: I failed to mention that the first 2 WriteLines succeed, but it never gets to the 3rd WriteLine.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using the old docker image to run your IronWorker tasks. Try to use "iron/mono" image for that. [This](https://github.com/iron-io/dockerworker/tree/master/mono) guide will walk you through HelloWorld .NET example.